# Signature certificate with time stamp and .p12 file Java 8

Tags: java, java-8, timestamp, ssl-certificate

I am developing a class in Java that consists of signing a certificate with a timestamp and a .p12 file in Base64 of the SHA-256 hash of the identity of an application.

So far I have the following development:

```
public class PruebaP12IA {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Apéndice de método generado automáticamente
        String idAplicacion = "idAplicacion";
        String ficheroP12 = "PRUEBAS.p12";
        char[] password = "password".toCharArray();
        String selloTiempo = "http://urlSelloTiempo/inputRequestTSA";
        
        
        //Calcular el hash SHA-256 de idAplicacion
        MessageDigest messageDigest = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
        messageDigest.update(idAplicacion.getBytes());
        byte[] hash = messageDigest.digest();
            
        //Cargar el certificado
        InputStream inStream = new FileInputStream(ficheroP12);
        KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12");
        ks.load(inStream, password);
        String alias = ks.aliases().nextElement();
        X509Certificate certificate = (X509Certificate) ks.getCertificate(alias);
            
        //Agregamos el sello de tiempo
        TimeStampToken token = new TimeStampToken(new CMSSignedData(selloTiempo.getBytes()));
        X509CertificateHolder holder = new X509CertificateHolder(certificate.getEncoded());
        /*SignerInformationVerifier siv = 
            new BcRSASignerInfoVerifierBuilder(new DefaultDigestAlgorithmIdentifierFinder(), new BcDigestCalculatorProvider()).build(holder);*/
        DefaultCMSSignatureAlgorithmNameGenerator nameGen = new DefaultCMSSignatureAlgorithmNameGenerator();
        DefaultSignatureAlgorithmIdentifierFinder sigAlgofinder = new DefaultSignatureAlgorithmIdentifierFinder();
        DefaultDigestAlgorithmIdentifierFinder hashAlgoFinder = new DefaultDigestAlgorithmIdentifierFinder();
        BcDigestCalculatorProvider calculator = new BcDigestCalculatorProvider();
        BcRSASignerInfoVerifierBuilder verifierBuilder = new BcRSASignerInfoVerifierBuilder(nameGen, sigAlgofinder, hashAlgoFinder, calculator);
        SignerInformationVerifier verifier = verifierBuilder.build(holder);
        token.validate(verifier);
            
        //Firmar el hash con la clave privada
        PrivateKey privateKey = (PrivateKey) ks.getKey(alias, password);
        Signature signature = Signature.getInstance("SHA256WithRSA");
        signature.initSign(privateKey);
        signature.update(hash);
        byte[] signedHash = signature.sign();
            
        //Verificar firma
        PublicKey publicKey = certificate.getPublicKey();
        Signature verificacion = Signature.getInstance("SHA256WithRSA");
        verificacion.initVerify(publicKey);
        verificacion.update(hash);
        boolean isValid = verificacion.verify(signedHash);
            
        if(isValid) {
            //Enconde the signed certificate in base64
            String signedCertificateBase64 = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(signedHash);
            //Mostrar el certificado firmado en base64
            System.out.println("Firma en BASE64: " + signedCertificateBase64);
        }
    }

}
```

Without the **Agregamos el sello de tiempo** part it works perfectly for me, but when I add it (it's necessary) it fails for me on the line *TimeStampToken token = new TimeStampToken(new CMSSignedData(timestamp.getBytes()));* . The following error occurs:

> org.bouncycastle.cms.CMSException: IOException reading content.   at
> org.bouncycastle.cms.CMSUtils.readContentInfo(Unknown Source)     at
> org.bouncycastle.cms.CMSUtils.readContentInfo(Unknown Source)     at
> org.bouncycastle.cms.CMSSignedData.(Unknown Source)     at
> pruebasborrar.PruebaP12IA.main(PruebaP12IA.java:61) Caused by:
> java.io.EOFException: DEF length 116 object truncated by 67   at
> org.bouncycastle.asn1.DefiniteLengthInputStream.toByteArray(Unknown
> Source)   at org.bouncycastle.asn1.ASN1InputStream.buildObject(Unknown
> Source)   at org.bouncycastle.asn1.ASN1InputStream.readObject(Unknown
> Source)   ... 4 more

Can anybody help me?

Thanks